# I made a function to fill shapes with color on canvas. Does anyone know why I still have some white space?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, canvas

picture of whitespace

[image: 1]

I'm making a drawing app and want to have a fill function. Right now, I'm just working on filling shapes, but my function still leaves me with some white space. Can anyone tell me why there's still whitespace?

```
    function drawTriangleBasic() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
        let height = 400 * Math.cos(Math.PI / 6);
    
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(50, 600);
        ctx.lineTo(450, 600);
        ctx.lineTo(250, 600 - height);
        ctx.closePath();
    
        // the outline
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#666666';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    drawTriangleBasic();
    //function doesnt know mouse position
    function fillerFunc(){
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
            // value++;
        let pixelWidth = Math.floor(width);
            // //let pixelHeight = Math.floor(height);
        let pixelX = 0;
        let pixelY = 1;

        for (let i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4){
            pixelX++
            if (pixelX === pixelWidth){
                pixelX -= pixelWidth;
                pixelY++;
            }
            let red = imgData.data[i];
            let green = imgData.data[i + 1];
            let blue = imgData.data[i + 2]
            let pixelLog = {
                red : red,
                green : green,
                blue : blue,
                x : pixelX,
                y : pixelY
            };
            pixelArray.push(pixelLog);

        }

        let borderArray = [];
        let borders = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < pixelArray.length; i++){

            if ((pixelArray[i].red !== 255 
                || pixelArray[i].green !== 255
                || pixelArray[i].blue !== 255)){
                for (let j = 0; j < pixelWidth - pixelArray[i].x ; j++){
                    let iteration = i + j;
                    if ((pixelArray[iteration].red === 255 
                        && pixelArray[iteration].green === 255
                        && pixelArray[iteration].blue === 255)){

                        let forwardsBoolean = false;
                        let backwardsBoolean = false;
                        for (let k = 0 ; k < pixelWidth - pixelArray[iteration].x; k++){
                            let plusFromWhite = iteration + k;
                            if (pixelArray[plusFromWhite].red !== 255 
                                || pixelArray[plusFromWhite].green !== 255
                                || pixelArray[plusFromWhite].blue !== 255){
                                    forwardsBoolean = true;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (forwardsBoolean === true){
                                ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
                                ctx.fillRect(pixelArray[iteration].x, pixelArray[iteration].y, 1, 1);
                            }
                    }
                }
                i += pixelWidth - pixelArray[i].x;
                }
            }
    }

    fillerFunc();
```

the logic is that it searches for a nonwhite pixel then looks for the next white pixel and checks if there's a nonwhite pixel in front of it if that condition is met then it fills the white pixel green

Comment: `let pixelY = 1;` doesn't sound correct. But you should really not use `fillRect` for this, just set the value in your ImageData and put it on the context.

Comment: @Kaiido This solved my issue thanks. I dont know why I didn't think to use putImageData